# Unzipping a huge file stalls the server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gzip

I want to extract a huge .tar.gz file but when I do extract it stalls the server. The server is write heavy and extracting seems to choke the disk. Is there a nice way to extract without stopping the world? I've tried the 'nice' and 'cpulimit' command but they don't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Run `du -h` on the file - what is it's size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you bottlenecking:  IO or CPU?

Have you tried `ionice` yet?  `-c3` (idle only) or `-n7` (lowest priority) should do the job.

Are you trying to retrieve a single file out of it, or just unpacking the full thing?

Comment: Unpacking full thing. It's a lot of files.

Comment: If you got a lot of RAM you're not using, you can try to unpack it there first.  But if the tarball is really huge, that's not gonna fit.  So I guess we're back to the basics of 'what is your bottleneck?'  when you run top, are your gunzip/tar programs in R or D state?  What do `vmstat`, `iostat -x`, `iotop` say?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `ionice` to the unzip process.  It may significantly slow your unzip, but you should be able to eliminate the stalling of other programs.

You may want to install `atsar` and look at your disk IO load.  If you have multiple disks, you may want to look at moving partitions to balance the load.